# How to use onStart in the new react native Gesture panhalder

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I wanted to convert my older React Native Gesture handling to the newer form.

I am creating a progress slider that allows a user to slide accross the width of the mobile screen back and forth.

I am trying to convert this:

```
const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: (_, ctx) => {
      ctx.startX = x.value;
    },
    onActive: (event, ctx) => {
      x.value = ctx.startX + event.translationX;
    },
    onEnd: (_, ctx) => {
          const thisSnapPoint = snapPoint(ctx.translationX, ctx.velocityX, [0, width]);
          sliderX.value = withSpring(thisSnapPoint);
    },
  });
```

to :

```
  const panGesture = useMemo(
    () =>
      Gesture.Pan()
        .onStart((e) => {})
        .onChange((e) => {
          startX.value = e.translationX;
        })
        .onEnd((e) => {
          const thisSnapPoint = snapPoint(e.translationX, e.velocityX, [0, width]);
          sliderX.value = withSpring(thisSnapPoint);
        }),
    [],
  );
```

However, it does not appear that the new [GestureDirector](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/gestures/gesture-detector) has contexts. How do I create the onStart To start where you previously left off?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably very late but I ran into the same issue with my slider and heres how I solved it (removed the slider logic):

Previous code:

```
   const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
        onStart: (_, ctx) => {
          ctx.startX = prevPositionX.value
        },
        onActive: (e, ctx) => {
         
          thumbPositionX.value = ctx.startX + e.translationX
  
        },
      })
```

New Code:

```
const prevPositionX = useSharedValue(0)

const gestureHandler = Gesture.Pan()
    .onStart(() => {
      prevPositionX.value = thumbPosition.value
    })
    .onUpdate((event) => {
      const newPosition = event.translationX + prevPositionX.value
      thumbPosition.value = newPosition
    })
```

Previously you were able to save the x position on ctx.startX and have it carry over to the next callback. Now instead I created another sharedvalue with the saved X position.